# Wasmer Error while importing "wasi_snapshot_preview1"."proc_exit": unknown import. Expected Function

Tags: c, compiler-errors, clang, linker-errors, webassembly

I use Clang to compile the following C file,

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int length(char* s) {
    return strlen(s);
}
int matrix(int row, int col) {
    printf("this is matrix\n");
    int a[row][col];
    int b[col][row];
    int r[row][row];
    for(int i = 0; i<row; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j<col; j++) {
            a[i][j] = rand()%1000+1;
            b[j][i] = rand()%1000+1;
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i<row; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j<row; j++) {
            r[i][j] = 0;
            for(int k = 0; k<col; k++) {
                r[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
    
    return r[row-1][row-1];
}
int main(){
    int a = matrix(10, 12);
    printf("a: %d\n", a);
    printf("length: %d\n", length("abcd"));
    return 0;
}
```

My compile command is as follows,

```sh
clang --sysroot home/user/wasi-sdk-12.0/share/wasi-sysroot/ \
-Wl,--export-all \
-o matrix.wasm matrix.c
```

And I use wasm2wat to translate wasm file into wat format. The file content the following import,

```
  (import "wasi_snapshot_preview1" "proc_exit" (func $__wasi_proc_exit (type 2))) 
  (import "wasi_snapshot_preview1" "fd_seek" (func $__wasi_fd_seek (type 3)))
  (import "wasi_snapshot_preview1" "fd_write" (func $__wasi_fd_write (type 4)))
  (import "wasi_snapshot_preview1" "fd_close" (func $__wasi_fd_close (type 5))) 
  (import "wasi_snapshot_preview1" "fd_fdstat_get" (func $__wasi_fd_fdstat_get (type 6)))
```

I run the webassembly file with wasmer,

```
wasmer run matrix.wasm --invoke matrix 10 12
```

Then the error appears,

```
error: failed to run `matrix.wasm`
╰─> 1: Error while importing "wasi_snapshot_preview1"."proc_exit": unknown import. Expected Function(FunctionType { params: [I32], results: [] })
```

I can run it successfully with

```
wasmer matrix.wasm
```

I don't know how to invoke a specific exported function correctly with these import lines. When I delete them, the program goes on well. However, because I delete the fd_write line, it does not print anything. How can I succefully execute this program with

```
wasmer matrix.wasm --invoke matrix 10 12
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add `--target=wasm32-wasi` to your compile command.

```
clang --target=wasm32-wasi --sysroot home/user/wasi-sdk-12.0/share/wasi-sysroot/ \
-Wl,--export-all \
-o matrix.wasm matrix.c
```

I tried this, everything works fine. If not this problem, maybe the version of `clang` and `wasi-sysroot` on your computer doesn't match.